# how can i get a picture from a webcam and upload it to salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, webcam, apex

I am using mediacapture to get the image from a webcam, but i dont know how to upload the picture to salesforce controllers. I can get the picture in any format: jpg,png,gif.

What is the next step?

Comment: Check out the link below: http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Image-Upload-using-visualforce-and-saving-in-custom-formula/td-p/335421

Comment: The problem with that is that is using an <apex:inputfile> element to upload the image i need to use the webcam. And i cannot change the value of the <apex:inputfile> from javascript

Comment: Check this article then and see if this works for you: http://himanshooseth1.blogspot.co.nz/2013/12/posting-base-64-data-in-visualforce.html